# The Delphi statement in C #

Tags: c#, delphi

In delphi we have

```
Self.Caption = 'ABCD';
```

and C#

```
new Form().Text = "ABCD";
```

but at Delphi we have instructions

```
Application.Title = 'XYZ';
```

This text is displayed in the ALT + TAB window.
How to do it in C #?

Explanation:
I need different text at the top of the window and different text in the Alt + Tab window

Comment: You could use Application.ProductName, but the value is get only and can't be set outside the project properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: What you should be asking is how to do X using C# GUI framework Y. Don't bring Delphi into this.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi, `TApplication` has its own window. It *used to be* that by default that window was the Win32 owner for all VCL Form/dialog windows. Because that window was the top-level window for the program, and owned windows do not have their own Taskbar buttons, that is why the `TApplication.Title` appeared on the Taskbar button and Alt-Tab dialog.  And it could be set to a different string value than `TForm` captions.

But, when the `TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar` property was added in Delphi 2007 for Vista support, that logic changed, making the `TApplication.MainForm` window now be the program's top-level owner by default.

When a top-level window has a Taskbar button, it also appears in the Alt-Tab dialog, and the window's caption text is what gets displayed in both.  So, if you want the Taskbar and Alt-Tab dialog to display a different text than what you set the `Form.Text` to, you will have to make the `Form` be owned by another window, and then set THAT window's caption text as needed.

Comment: Question asks how to achieve this in C#

Comment: I'm aware of that.  My last sentence should cover that.  Setting a `Form`'s `Text` should be enough to specify the text that is displayed on the Form's Taskbar button and Alt-Tab dialog entry. Unless the question is how to display a different text, in which case the answer is - you don't, unless you change the `Form`'s Win32 owner to be another window, then set THAT window's `Text` instead. Which is how Delphi used to do it

Comment: That is literally the question. Read the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: Well, I just answered it then